# Solve $6^{x+8} = 4^{x-1}$

Tags: logarithms

I tried doing $log_6\left(6^{x+8}\right) = log_6{4^{x-1}}$

I got stuck, and I don't think that was the right route.

Comment: **Hint:** $\log_b(x^y)=y\log_b(x)$

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Log rules strike again!

Comment: For all variations of your problem  of the  kind (e.g., with $x+8$ replaced by $x+3$) the solution can never be in whole numbers. Because LHS would be divisible by 3 and the  RHS would not be.

Answer (score 6):

The OP's start was fine.  We rewrite the left side as $x+8$, and pull the exponent out of the right side, to get $$x+8=(x-1)\log_64$$
We expand the right side to get $$x+8=x(\log_64)-\log_64$$
then subtract $8+x\log_64$ from both sides, to get
$$x-x\log_64=-8-\log_64$$
We now factor out $x$ to get $$x(1-\log_64)=-8-\log_64$$
Lastly, we divide by $1-\log_64$ to get $$x=\frac{-8-\log_64}{1-\log_64}$$

Comment: Can't I use change of base here to get a number?

Comment: This is a number, albeit a somewhat messy one.  It is possible to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't necessarily matter which base you are in, you can solve this as follows $$6^{x+8}=4^{x-1}\iff \log(6^{x+8})=\log(4^{x-1})$$ then, by rules of the logarithm, $$(x+8)\log 6=(x-1)\log 4$$
now, by the distributive property for real numbers,
$$(x+8)\log 6=(x-1)\log 4 \iff x\log 6 + 8\log 6 = x\log 4 -\log4$$
and so

$$x\log6-x\log 4=-8\log 6 - \log4$$
again by the distributive property
$$x(\log6-\log4)=-8\log 6 - \log4$$
and since $(\log 6 - \log 4)\neq 0$, we can divide both sides by it to achieve:

$$x=\frac{-8\log 6 - \log 4}{\log6-\log4}$$

Comment: Note that in base $6$ we get vadim123's answer. I posted this because (partially I had almost finished it when another answer was posted) and I want to emphasize the interelation between exponents and the logarithm. The base of the logarithm is not so important as to what it is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the logs of exponents

$$(6x+8)*\log_6(6)=(x-1)*\log_6(4)$$

2. Rewrite bases

$$(6x+8)*\frac{\log(6)}{\log(6)}=(x-1)*\frac{\log(4)}{\log(6)}$$

3. Since $\frac{\log(6)}{\log(6)} = 1$,

$$(6x+8)=(x-1)*\frac{\log(4)}{\log(6)}$$

4. Thus, dividing $\frac{(6x+8)}{(x-1)}$:

$$\frac{(6x+8)}{(x-1)}=\frac{\log(4)}{\log(6)}$$

5. Then, after further solving the equation, we get the value of $x$:

$$x=-\frac{\log(2592)}{\log(108)}$$

Comment: The original equation was $6^{x + 8} = 4^{x - 1}$.  If you take base $6$ logarithms of both sides, you should obtain $(x + 8)\log_6 6 = (x - 1)\log_6 4$.